# How to pass debounce wait parameter

Tags: javascript, lodash, mobx

I am using *debounce* from *lodash* library in *mobx* store:

```
setSettingsDebounced = debounce(flow(function* (which) {
    try {
      yield patchLightSettings(which);
    }
}.bind(this)), 200);
```

This method is called like this:

```
this.setSettingsDebounced('something');
```

This all works fine, my problem is: How should I pass the **wait** (which is currently hard-coded to **200**) parameter for debounce so that is still works as expected?

Comment: Just wrap inside a functional closure,..

Answer (score 3):

You can simply wrap the debounce like this:

```js
const DELAY = 2000
const debounceWithParam = (fn, timeInMs) => _.debounce(fn, timeInMs)
const myFn = () => console.log('FOOOOO')

const myDebouncedFn = debounceWithParam(myFn, DELAY)

myDebouncedFn()
myDebouncedFn()

// Wait for one "FOOOOO" in the console :)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that only one `FOOOOO` would be shown although we did call out new function 2 times.

So in your case:

```
 setSettingsDebounced = debounceWithParam(setSettingsFn, DELAY);
```

Comment: Hi, and what if I want to use it with variable DELAY like 
`debounceWithParam(()=>...., 100);`
`debounceWithParam(()=>...., 1000); `
etc